# Running framebuffer application over ssh with display on TFT

Tags: ssh, pitft, framebuffer

I've got a RPi 2 running Raspi OS 2020-12-02 with *Adafruit 3.5" TFT display* - the display is configured correctly and displays console messages and as well can display images, for example when I run `fbi /usr/share/rpd-wallpaper/trees.jpg` while logged in with a keyboard directly on the RPi.

However when I SSH to it I'm unable to run any framebuffer apps like the above. All I get is an error:

```
[ssh-session] pi@camview:~ $ fbi /usr/share/rpd-wallpaper/trees.jpg
ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Inappropriate ioctl for device (not a linux console?)
```

Any idea how to convince `fbi` or any other graphical app for that matter to use the TFT display even if I'm logged in over ssh?

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to export DISPLAY to get that to work
i have been using FBV instead of FBI and i like it a lot better and it also supports fs scaling too

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/118500)